# Password Reset with GUI Improvements

Tags: powershell, windows-forms-designer

I am working on a Password Reset Script with a GUI and have 3 questions If any body is able to help me :) the premise is that when I user scans their card it will show their username and password, it functions as it should be I want to develop it further.

1. If the box is empty and ‘okay’ is selected then it uses every row in the CSV, is there a way to set it up so the OK button can't be pressed until something is entered. The RFID scanner used always hits a return.
2. After the pop box has been displayed I want to add a timer for 15 seconds before it closed and then when the pop-up box disappears it then asks for the next person to scan their card. As it stands at the moment, when the message box appears it closes the original form. Is there any way for me to keep the entry form open rather than it shutting, and show the message box over the top of the form? I basically want to reset the form after the user has been given their details.
3. When I have the form created at the top I can style it. Am I able to do the same for the message box so it can be styled? Thank you so much in advance.

Any help would be massively appreciated. I am still learning the basics of PowerShell

Code

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$Spreadsheet = Import-CSV "C:\Desktop\Password Reset\Passwords.csv" -Header First,Second,Username,Password,RFID

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Password Reset System'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,600) #Box Size
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$Form.BackColor = "#A4F9F4"
$Form.ForeColor = "#000000"

$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(350,350) #OK Button Location
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,24) #OK Button Size
$okButton.Text = 'OK'
$okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $okButton
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(270,300) #Label Location
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) #Label Size
$label.Text = 'Scan your Card:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(270,320) #Textbox Location
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) #Textbox Size
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)
$form.Topmost = $true
$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $resetCardNumber = $textBox.Text
    $targetUser = $Spreadsheet | Where-Object RFID -eq $resetCardNumber
}

if($targetUser){
  Set-ADAccountPassword $targetUser.Username -Reset -NewPassword (Convertto-Securestring -AsPlainText $targetUser.Password -Force)

  #Write-Host "Password reset to $($targetUser.Password) for $($targetUser.First) $($targetUser.Second) "($($targetUser.Username))" with card number $($targetUser.RFID)"
  
  [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Your Username: $($targetUser.Username) `nYour Password: $($targetUser.Password) ")

}
else {
  #Write-Host "User with Card Number '$resetCardNumber' could not be found!"

  [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Your Username could not be found in the system")
}
```

CSV File below:

```
First,Second,Username,Password,RFID
John,Smith,JS219401,YourPassword,84192011
Barry,Henry,BH219401,YourPassword,92832839
```

Comment: Hi Theo, this worked absloutely perfect thank you. Do you know of any way possible to make it so that the CSV file that is being imported is the latest modified within a folder? I have tried numerous ways and can't seem to get this working. I have tried the CSV filter and last modified but it just wont import

Comment: Try `$csvFile = (Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\TheFolder' -Filter '*.csv' -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1).FullName` Then use `$Spreadsheet = Import-CSV -Path $csvFile ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, below (read the inline comments) explains your questions 1 and 2.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Spreadsheet = Import-CSV "C:\Desktop\Password Reset\Passwords.csv" -Header First,Second,Username,Password,RFID

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text          = 'Password Reset System'
$form.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,600) #Box Size
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$Form.BackColor     = "#A4F9F4"
$Form.ForeColor     = "#000000"

$okButton              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(350,350) #OK Button Location
$okButton.Size         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,24) #OK Button Size
$okButton.Text         = 'OK'

# remove the next line if you want the mainform to stay open
# $okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK

# initialize the button's Enabled status to $false
$okButton.Enabled = $false

# add event handler code for the button's Click event
# this can only be the case if the button was Enabled
$okButton.Add_Click({
    $resetCardNumber = $textBox.Text
    $targetUser = $Spreadsheet | Where-Object {$_.RFID -eq $resetCardNumber}
    if($targetUser){
      Set-ADAccountPassword $targetUser.Username -Reset -NewPassword (Convertto-Securestring -AsPlainText $targetUser.Password -Force)
      #Write-Host "Password reset to $($targetUser.Password) for $($targetUser.First) $($targetUser.Second) "($($targetUser.Username))" with card number $($targetUser.RFID)"
      [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Your Username: $($targetUser.Username) `nYour Password: $($targetUser.Password) ")
    }
    else {
      #Write-Host "User with Card Number '$resetCardNumber' could not be found!"
      [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Your Username could not be found in the system")
    }
    # reset the form by clearing out the textbox
    $textBox.Text = ''  # this also triggers the OK button to become disabled
})

$form.AcceptButton = $okButton
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)

$label          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(270,300) #Label Location
$label.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) #Label Size
$label.Text     = 'Scan your Card:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textBox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(270,320) #Textbox Location
$textBox.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) #Textbox Size

# add a TextChanged event handler to toggle the OK button's Enabled status
$textBox.Add_TextChanged({
    $okButton.Enabled = (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($this.Text))
})

$form.Controls.Add($textBox)
$form.Topmost = $true
$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

# Important, remove the form from memory when done
$form.Dispose()
```

I'm not really sure what you mean with the third question though: *"Am I able to do the same for the message box so it can be styled?"*

Since you're using a `System.Windows.MessageBox`, there is nothing you can do about its default appearance, since *A message box is a prefabricated modal dialog box that displays a text message to a user.*
If you want a self-styled messagebox, you'll have to create one yourself.